# How to show a loading window in webview

Tags: java, android

This is my `Webview` fragment. Is there anyway to add a loading circle till loading `HTML` page..

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Retrieving the currently selected item number
    int position = getArguments().getInt("position");

    String url = getArguments().getString("url");

    // List of rivers
    String[] menus = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menus);

    // Creating view corresponding to the fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);

    // Updating the action bar title
    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle(menus[position]);

    //Initializing and loading url in webview
    final WebView webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView); 
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.loadUrl(url);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html"); }
            });

    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebViewClient callbacks. There are OnPageFinished() callback and lots of other useful things.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url) {
       ......some code here..
   }
 });
```

So all you need to do is show progress right after webview.loadUrl() method and dismiss it in onPageFinished() callback method.

Comment: Sorry, This is not place to help code. Try your self. Read WebViewClient and onPageFinished  method by google search then implement it.

Comment: I have seen people give answer with perfect codes.. why dont u? I m a newbie so i need help..

Answer (score 0):

```
**main.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/framelayout"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:foregroundGravity="center" 
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<WebView
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
   android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
   android:scrollbars="none" />

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loading_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:drawingCacheQuality="high"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/loading_bar"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:padding="10dp"
       android:text="Loading. Please Wait"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:typeface="normal" />

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/loading_bar"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView webview;
boolean first_time;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    first_time = true;
     webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    // setting the required pluggins
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient( new MyWebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    //Zoom Controls
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
     // below set html url  
         webview.loadUrl("set_html_url");
}

  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
ProgressBar bar;
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    return false;
} 
 @Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     bar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading_bar); 
     bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     bar.bringToFront();
     if(!first_time)
         findViewById(R.id.loading_ll).setBackgroundColor(color.transparent);
         findViewById(R.id.loading_ll).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

 @Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     first_time = false;
     bar.clearFocus();
     bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     findViewById(R.id.loading_ll).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
}
}


 @Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(webview.getUrl().contains(getString(R.string.START_PAGE_PATH)))
    moveTaskToBack(true);
else
    webview.loadUrl(getString(R.string.START_PAGE_PATH));
}
}
```